# Closed with reference to 404

Tags: support, closed-questions

This question

[How to generate the following $n$-level $n$-particle singlet state?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/9001/5280)

was closed with reference to another

https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8668/how-to-generate-the-following-n-level-n-particle-singlet-state

which leads me to 404: Page not found

Comment: The deleted question appears to have been roomba'd but there's no explanation anywhere of how it got closed in the first place, so I've reopened the question (which you linked to first and was asked later), as that's easier

Comment: @Mithrandir24601 ok thanks...

Comment: @Mithrandir24601 don't questions with a negative score and no answers with a positive score eventually get roomba'ed after a bit?  The deleted question and the new question appear to be exactly the same, except the newer question has a preface.  I supposed the question is coming from the same source.  draks... I suspect the newer question is getting upvotes I suspect because the preface adds a polite and respectful preface.  The question that was deleted was downvoted I suspect because it appeared to be a data-dump without any motivation or barely any effort.

Comment: @MarkS ... Of course... The question had been closed in the past, then reopened, so I was thinking of a different roomba script